# What is this DiscordAPI Unauthorized error coming from?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am developing a new bot for my fiance. I had just gotten through setting it up when I started getting this message as an error :

> (node:2540) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: 401: Unauthorized

I did a quick "hello" reply command to see if it is the entire bot, and it is not. It only causes problems with the code below. I highly doubt the code below is right, because I am having the authorized error before I can work on debugging.

```
//!createpride [@pride name], [pride leader username @ mention] 

        const Discord = require('discord.js');
        const client = new Discord.Client();
        const config = require("../config.json");
        client.login(config.token);
        client.prideleaders = require("./prideleaders.json")
        const fs = require("fs");

        let userInput = message.content.slice(13);
        var userInputArray = userInput.split(", ")
        var PrideName = userInputArray[0]
        var NameOfPride = userInputArray[0]
        console.log(PrideName)
        var Head = userInputArray[1]
        console.log(Head)

        let user = Head.toString();

        if (user.includes("!")) {
            var HeadID = user.split("!")[1].split(">")[0];
        } else {
            var HeadID = user.split("@")[1].split(">")[0];
        }

        let LeaderUser = client.fetchUser(`${HeadID}`)
        let LeaderUsername = LeaderUser.username

        console.log(HeadID)

        let NewPride = PrideName = {
            leader: LeaderUsername,
            leaderID: HeadID
        };

        let NewPrideString = JSON.stringify(NewPride)

        fs.writeFile('./prideleaders.json', NewPrideString, err => {
            if (err){ 
                console.log(err);
            } else {
            message.channel.send(`${NameOfPride} has been created with ${Head} as the leader!`)
            }
          })
```

I have never seen this error before and really found no ways of solving it... I never really work with JSON files either, so I have no idea if it could relate to that. Any ideas? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Is `client.login(...)` in the command execution or is it just there for reference?

Comment: I copied and pasted from another command, so that is just a remnant. The line was there when the code was working properly, so I don't think that is the cause.

Comment: You should only login to the same client once. Try attaching `catch(console.error)` to the method and see if that resolves the unhanded promise rejection message. If it does, that's the source of your error.

Comment: I just removed the client.login line, before I tried adding the catch you just suggested, and the error changed to `(node:20320) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.` I'm not even sure where the token request is in this command.

Comment: Is there any stack with that error? Some kind of pointer to a line or method would be helpful. Also, can you double-check that the token is correct, and the file is at the right path when your client attempts to log in (every place you do)?